# How to set up shared folder cannot place exe files

Tags: windows

Expected Result :

- can't place exe file
- can't rename txt to exe that is exe file renamed to txt
- can't execute exe renaming txt file

Objective :
To avoid the portable exe executed  by company colleagues.

What I've tried :
I tried to use everything daily to find out the exe file and remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use File Server Resource Manager to block any executable from being saved to network shares.

For more details about FSRM, you could refer to the following article:

[File Server Resource Manager (FSRM) overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/fsrm/fsrm-overview)